# Processing multiple tasks in parallel (in java-8)

Tags: java, java-8

Is there anything wrong with this method...

```
public static void runinParallel(final List<Runnable> tasks){ 
    tasks.parallelStream().forEach(t -> t.run());
}
```

assuming that it is safe to execute tasks in parallel.

Comment: For one thing, there's no way to control the level of parallelism. For another, it doesn't compile.

Comment: If you are doing threads and using java 8, have you considered `CompletableFuture` its a much more useful api for running threads and much easier to manage them.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this have a list of tasks and an ExecutorService

```
List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

After that add all the tasks you want to run in parallel threads , the new fixedThreadPool takes parameter which specifies the no of threads to want to run in parallel , so if you have 10 tasks 5 will run first and after that the thread that finishes execution will move on to the next task.
you can also use a cachedThreadPool.

Then Submit these tasks to the ExecutorService

```
for (Task t : tasks) {
    threadPool.submit(t);
}
```

and after that remeber to close the threadpool .

```
threadPool.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 2):

yes you can do that. This is more functional way of doing things but keep it in mind that you will not have control over the threads invoked.  Instead of `Runnable`, consider using `java.util.concurrent.Future`

```
       public static void runinParallel(final List<Future> tasks){ 
            tasks.parallelStream().forEach(t -> { threadPool.submit(t);
    // collect the tasks in a collection and use it for future references
 } );
    }
```